# Comparing with a sequence function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have a big data set of positive integers, inside it, I found a sequence of integers $k$ that looks like that $\{k_1,k_2...k_i\}$

Accordingly I have $f(n)$

- $f(1)= k_1$
- $f(2)= k_2$
- $f(3)= k_3$
- $f(i+2)= k_3$

**How can I solve the next equation?**

$$\frac{d}{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{i=x}{f(i)}$$
 - $d$ is a positive integer

*I came to this problem while been working on my [algorithm](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272239/find-sequences-in-a-big-data-set-of-integers).*

Here is an example to how $f(n)$ might looks like

$$1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2...$$

Comment: $k_3=f(3)=f(1+2)=k_2$?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Sorry I don't understand the question

Comment: If $k_2\neq k_3$ your function is not well defined if $i=1$ is allowed.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I see it now. Tnx I edit the question

Comment: you have $d=x (k_1+k_2) + x(x-2)k_3$ which is a quadratic equation. Thus it is even solvable explictitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not well posed, so according to your example, I will suppose that your question is the following :

Assume that $f(n)$ is a periodic sequence of integer with period $p$ (in your example, p=4). How to solve ${d\over x} = \sum_{i=1}^x f(i)$. 
It is clear that the first stage in such problems is to determine $$S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x f(i).$$
In general, you can use the following method: by definition, $f(n+p)=f(n)$ so you have a recurrence relation. The solution is very simple: let $k$ be the first multiple of $p$ before $x$. So, the sequence contains exactly $q={k\over p}$ periods between $1$ and $k$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{k}f(i) = qs$, where $s$ denotes the sum of $f(i)$ over a single period. Now, $$S(x) = qs + \sum_{i=k+1}^x f(i).$$ This is the desired solution.

Let us return to the original problem. You want to find a solution of $${d\over x} = S(x).$$
Of course, in general there will not exist an exact solution, but you can find an approximate one by writing $$d= xS(x).$$ Since the function $xS(x)$ is strictly increasing and can be easily computed for every $x$, a dichotomic search quickly leads to the best possible approximation : simply begin with $x_1 = 1$ and $y_1 = d$, then find the middle $m=[{x_1+y_1\over 2}]$, test if $mS(m) > d$ or $mS(m) < d$, and put $x_2= m$ and $y_2 = y_1$ if $mS(m)< d$, or $y_2=m$ and $x_2=x_1$ otherwise, etc.